# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Per-clause not recognized: pmAspect

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have a problem with the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` configuration tag.

I have added *aspectjrt.jar* and *aspectjweaver.jar*, but my setup still is not working.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ser' defined in file \[C:\\Users\\kunar\\eclipse-workspace\\Spring\\AopProj1\\target\\classes\\com\\krk\\service\\ServiceTest.class\]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ser' defined in file \[C:\\Users\\kunar\\eclipse-workspace\\Spring\\AopProj1\\target\\classes\\com\\krk\\service\\ServiceTest.class\]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Per-clause not recognized: pmAspect
    at org.aspectj.internal.lang.reflect.AjTypeImpl.getPerClause(AjTypeImpl.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AspectMetadata.\<init\>(AspectMetadata.java:103)
```

```java
@Component
@Aspect("pmAspect") 
public class AspectTest {
  @Around(value = "execution(int com.krk.service.ServiceTest.a*(..))")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint php) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("before method call");
    Object ob=php.proceed();
    System.out.println("after method call");
    return ob;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Feel free to post it on GitHub, then edit your question, linkingto it. Please also be a bit less sloppy in formatting your code, making the question look less chaotic and more readable. Then I will be glad to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Besides, why would you need AspectJ Maven Plugin for Spring AOP? Why did you select that tag for your question? And why are you using different versions - both very outdated - for AspectJ weaver and runtime in your Maven POM?

Comment: P.S.: I just completely reworded and reformatted your question to make reading it hurt other people's eyes a bit less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you use `@Aspect("pmAspect")` is obviously wrong. It seems as if you want to name the aspect,but you should do that in `@Component` instead, or possibly in `@Bean`, if for any reason in another case you want to use a factory method in your configuration class.

If you look at the [`@Aspect` javadoc](https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Aspect.java#L28-L32), you will notice that the `value` parameter is not for naming but for specifying an instantiation type, if you need something other than a singleton aspect. You cannot just put anything into a string parameter and simply assume that it will be interpreted as a name or label.

Therefore, the solution to your problem is to simply use `@Aspect` without any parameters.

One more thing: You do not need both AspectJ weaver and runtime in your POM. The weaver already contains the runtime. And you should upgrade to a more recent AspectJ version, not just copy and paste random snippets from the WWW. The latest version would be:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.19</version>
</dependency>
```

But that is not the root cause of your problem.